# Filtering a list to find elements divisible by a number

Tags: collections, groovy

I have a list in Groovy and I would like to get out of all elements to a new list which can be divisible by 6.

```
 def someList = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The new list should be: `[6, 12]`

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `findAll`

```
def someList = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] 

def divisibleBySix = someList.findAll { it % 6 == 0 }

assert divisibleBySix == [6, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [findAll](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)). The example in the official api documentation is practically identical to your case:

```
someList.findAll { it % 6 == 0 }
```